# Dos claves foráneas repetidas que hacen relación a una misma tabla

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, diseño, modelorelacional

tengo este diseño de Vuelos y me surgió la duda si se puede hacer lo siguiente, tener dos llaves foráneas en la tabla Vuelos que hacen referencia a una misma tabla Aeropuerto. Ya he intentado normalizar hasta la 3FN pero siempre me da el mismo resultado. Esto es recomendable hacerlo así o existe una mejor forma?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si un vuelo tiene dos aeropuertos, por qué no iba a poder tener dos claves foráneas hacia la tabla de aeropuertos?? Claro que es correcto hacerlo así

Comment: la verdad no lo se, solo senti que podria dar problemas al hacer consultas con los inner join y porque son dos claves repetidas

Comment: donde son repetidas?? y esta perfecto..

Comment: no hay ningún problema. Es un caso donde se nota la eficiencia de la tercera forma normal junto con la integridad relacional.